# WPF Custom Control Templated to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate

I am looking at making a small change to [WPFGrowlNotification](https://github.com/IvanLeonenko/WPFGrowlNotification) project.

I considered making it a custom-control but came across one big snag: **The actual Growl notification is a Window**. This means I can't move its styling to a ControlTemplate because a `Window` can't be in a ControlTemplate (probably because it needs to be the root control).

[image: Growl Notifications]

I think it's currently implemented as a window because it pops over the main window to display the notification in the top-right corner of the user's screen. However, this requires that the control is initialized within the code-behind. I'd like to make it more compatible with the MVVM design pattern.

So:

- Is there a way to template a custom-control so that it appears outside the boundaries of it's parent window?
- Is the Popup class a viable option for providing the same functionality while avoiding the templating limitations of Window?

Comment: Can't you have your custom control derive from Window also, then just change the content template of the window itself?

Comment: @NETscape: _"Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual."_ Probably same reason you can't have a `Window` in the `ControlTemplate`: It would cause you to have a Window that isn't at the root of the visual tree any time you added the custom control to anything.